# Handle an exception in a while loop

Tags: python, exception, while-loop

I'm calling a function that will raise an Exception if a webpage hasn't loaded yet. I want to wait 2 seconds and then try again until the page is loaded.

I tried this:

```
while(True):
    try:
        some_function()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
```

but it escapes after the first iteration.

How do I escape if when the Exception isn't raised?

Comment: Because you're probably calling it on a valid web page.

Comment: this will only execute once no matter what value ``some_function()`` returns.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Unless an exception is raised.

Comment: Have you verified the correctness of `some_functiont`?

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, if I put a bigger delay, like 30seconds it works. but I don't want to wait that long if isn't necessary

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def some_function(){
    try:
        #logic to load the page. If it is successful, it will not go to except.
        return True
    except:
        #will come to this clause when page will throw error.
        return False
    }
    
while(True):
    if some_function():
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(2)
        continue
```

Comment: @Ev. Kounis:- Saw your suggestion. But I think flag == True is not reqd inside while. Even if it's infinite, it will break based on the if inside while. Hence the checking of flag will do the part! your suggestions plz!

Comment: true but then why initialize it?

Comment: at the top...the topmost line is initializing the flag!

Comment: but WHY? it is not needed with your version of the code.

Comment: ya not explicitly declaring flag as any boolean will work as well....when the return is anyways True/False. Just declared to make it more simple! :)

Comment: No one mentioning the curly braces in this answer? :o

Answer (score 4):

Why not this:

```
res = False
while (res == False):
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        some_function()
        res = boolean(some_function())
    except:
        continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything in the try block is going to be executed until an `Exception` is raised, which case the `except` block would be called.

So you're breaking during the first iteration.

I think you mean:

```
while(True):
    try:
        some_function()
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
        break
```

When the exception is raised, the while loop will be broken.

Comment: How do I escape if when the exception isn't raised

Comment: my understanding is that he wants to keep trying until ``try`` succeeds.

Answer (score -1):

This is because if you break, it'll break out of the while loop. Get rid of break and indent except.

```
while(True):
    try:
        some_function()
        if check_loaded:
            break
    except:
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: and what would ``check_loaded`` be?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the break statement. Break is supposed to exit out of the loop block after the first.

Comment: True story but that's not the only problem. There has to be some kind of exit strategy, otherwise this will run forever.

Comment: he just ask why it escapes after first loop...